# Rails does not take into account sass code when changing to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I change my environment to production I get this:

```
Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1
```

And it only takes into account pure css rules, not sass (file `application.css.sass`).

Why is that?

I don't get any precompile errors... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default extension/syntax for sass-rails is scss. sass have to be enabled extra

```
  application.css.scss
```